# Irish Visa missing Document

Tags: visa, ireland, refusal

I had come to realize after I submitted my online application  for critical skills employment that I had not mentioned my refusal to the UK in September 2014 (I honestly forgot completely ).
So I had written the note below as instructed to give to the officer with all the rest of the supporting documents which discovered that it was not submitted as I found the original and copy after I returned to Cairo so I don’t think I submitted it

So I did call the embassy in Alex this morning  and they notified me that the person whom took the papers and whom I met yesterday is out for vacation and they don’t know when she will be back

Also the refusal stamp is clear on the previous passport copy and not intended to be hidden I only want to give the refusal reason per my memory  along with the clarification

I just want to submit my hand written paper as not to be understood as fraudulent information

I also want like to note out that I have been issued an Australian visa and a US visa after the UK refusal

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Seems clear to me. The OP wants to submit to the embassy his handwritten note correcting the written information he handed to the interviewing officer, and asks (by implication, I agree) how to do this.

Comment: @Ebboo It seems to me that your chances of getting the decision-maker to accept submission of your paper at this stage of the process could very well depend on how you answered the question in the application about previous refusals. If you answered ‘yes’ they’re more likely to accept your paper; even if you don’t get it to them you will have answered truthfully albeit without a full explanation. If you answered ‘no’, and then also forgot to hand in your paper at the interview, it’s more likely they’ll enforce the interview as the cut-off point and refuse to accept the paper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wish to get the physical piece of paper to the embassy in Alex, you can either mail it, courier it, or try to hand-deliver it.

No method will guarantee that your information will be received and considered before the embassy has made its decision to grant or deny your application, nor that receipt of the information will result in a grant. You might also consider submitting a withdrawal of your application, if you think that starting afresh with a new application would be a better approach.

Whatever you do, do it quickly. If you have an email address (or even the telephone number) of the consular official who interviewed you, use them so the official learns about the missing information **before** making a decision. Your chances of success in obtaining a visa in the future will be reduced if a decision to deny this application is reached before they receive your updated information.

Comment: I did call and email hopefully they will get it but I guess since I acted after only one day that I could at least appeal

Comment: An appeal is likely to address only the correctness of the visa official's actions with respect to _the application before him at the time of decision_, and would not take account of any information submitted by you after the decision had been made.

Comment: Thanks David I emailed both the embassy and consulate , wish me luck